# Limit DevMode to admin users?

Tags: craft3, login, devmode

Is there an easy way to enable devMode only to users logged in with specific permissions?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by „show devMode“?

Comment: I want to enable dev mode, which is usually done in the config file. But I only want to show it to people logged in as admin.

Comment: If you mean the visual devMode indicator you may be able to inject some CSS that hides it for some users. You may write a small module for this. Note that the devMode is not meant to be used in production environments. Maybe there is another solution to your problem.

Comment: No, not dev mode in the control panel, but on the live site. For example, users who are not logged in as admin should see a regular 404 page when they hit something that would trigger it. But logged in admin users would get the dev mode messaging, for troubleshooting.

Comment: I see, if Craft allows you to set config values during runtime then you could set the `devMode` variable to `true` or `false` based on the current user.

Comment: I don't think that's possible.

Comment: You can see what the devMode does here: https://craftcms.com/guides/what-dev-mode-does. I don‘t think you can disable this. Would a multi environment setup solve your problem, like setting up a staging server on a different domain? This is quite common practice. Anyways, what is the goal behind enabling devMode for admins at all?

Comment: Yes, a multi-environment set up would address the issue. I am a holdout, I have just a production box. The goal for enabling dev mode so I can troubleshoot things while not showing those ugly errors to anyone else. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The goal for enabling dev mode so I can troubleshoot things while not showing those ugly errors to anyone else.

If that's all you're looking for, there is a per-user account setting for this under the user account's preferences:

[image]

Comment: How did I miss that? Excellent, thanks.